# Make this into a Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

How do you wrap this as a Javascript closure to make var entryString work inside the `addEventListener` method

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucheron/XVq3n/11/

```
    addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
    var entryString = '';

addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
    var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
    entryString += '<li>';
    entryString += text;
    entryString += '</li>';
    var entry = '';
    entry.innerHTML = entryString; 
    addItem.appenChild(document.createTextNode(entry));
});
```

Comment: Every function is a closure. What are you trying to do? You could just put `entryString` inside your Anonymous function. Also, `entry.innerHTML` will not work, since that is not a DOM Node.

Comment: I'm trying to create a list of items. When you type in the input text box, then it adds items to list. I have included my js fiddle link above

Comment: @PHPglue—the commonly accepted meaning of [closure in javascript](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) is where a function continues to hold references to lexical environments of functions that have finished executing (e.g. the module pattern). Where a scope chain consists entirely of running execution contexts, no closure is said to have been formed. ECMA-262 uses the term "closure" in regard to functions in various places (e.g. [§11.1.5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)) but there is no formal definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');

addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
    var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
    var entry = document.createElement("li");
    entry.innerHTML = text; 
    addItem.appendChild(entry);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/XVq3n/13/

Comment: OK thanks. I suppose if i move the vars outside the addEventListener, then it works as a closure, right?

Comment: Glad I could help!  The function will have the vars outside of the it within scope so it would be creating as simple closure.

Comment: How would you concatenate the `<li>`'s rather than using `createElement("li")`

Answer (score 1):

You already have a "closure" per say in that you have an enclosing functional block where you can declare the scope of `entryString`.  Simply add a `var entryString` just below the function declaration.  There's a lot of other stuff wrong here though. You're also trying to assign `innerHTML` of a string, and then appending that. I would refactor your function as follows:

```
addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // create a new <li>
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  // take the text from #listItem and put it into the li
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('listItem').value));
  // append the new <li> to #output
  document.getElementById('output').appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: Now I am pretty clear on what is going on. Thank you for the detailed explanation.